# Is it safe to rely on order by in group statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a table like this:

```
id; day; daily
1; 2013-07-01; 50.00
1; 2013-07-02; 60.00
1; 2013-07-03; 70.00
1; 2013-07-04; 80.00
```

this query:

```
SELECT
   id
   day,
   daily,
   SUM(daily) total
FROM
   table
GROUP BY
   id
ORDER BY
   day DESC
```

returns:

```
1; 2013-07-04; 80.00; 260.00
```

Everything fine so far.

My question is: is it safe to rely on the order by statement for all "unsummed" values? I need to be sure that I read the value of "daily" of the row with the highest date.

Thank you,

Peter

PS I have found a couple of threads dealing with similar questions, but they all used subqueries which is no option in my case.

Comment: Are you saying you want the `total` to be a running balance? And further, why isn't a sub query an option in your case?

Comment: Thanks everybody - but in sense of the question I guess Jon answered it correctly (thanks for not RTFMing me). But I'll give Gordon's approach a try before committing my self to splitting the queries...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is absolutely not safe to rely on this. In fact this construction is logically meaningless ([it is invalid SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html)), and the fact that MySql still allows you to do it is... bad. Here's an excerpt from the manual:

> However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. **The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.**
>   Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be
>   influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set
>   occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect
>   which values within each group the server chooses.

If you want to get the last row and a sum, then just use two separate queries: one for the last row, and one for the sum.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing weird about this is that the query absolutely is doing what I want... what a pity. I think I'll go for two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is perfectly fine.  It just doesn't do what you want:

```
SELECT id, day, daily, SUM(daily) total
FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

The fields `day` and `daily` are taken from arbitrary rows in the data.  The `ORDER BY` is processed *after* the group by.  The right way to do what you want is with a subquery, or with the following `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` method:

```
SELECT id, max(day) as day,
       substring_index(group_concat(daily order by day desc), ',', 1) as daily,
       SUM(daily) as total
FROM table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY day DESC;
```

This turns `daily` into a string.  If you want it as a number, convert it back.